# Present modal view controller on top of Quick Look PreviewController results in checkerboard-screen?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

Situation: my app needs to present a full screen modal view whenever it becomes active (from background) to ask the user for a PIN. All fine.
Unless: if the user previews a file using `QLPreviewController`, leaves the app and comes back, the PIN input controller will be presented modally from the `QLPreviewController` which I'm keeping a reference to. The PIN input is shown but when it dismisses, I see a checkerboard-styled background which is even scrollable. Seems to be some leftover of the PreviewController but the actual preview data is no longer shown. Any idea what could cause that?

Do I have to reload the contents of the preview somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and I've managed to pin down the problem to either `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` methods. My solution was to subclass `QLPreviewController` and overwrite those methods with **empty** implementation i.e. skipping the call to `super`. I don't know if it's very safe, though I haven't encountered issues and it solved my problem.

Comment: Did you also get the checkerboard background?

Comment: To answer your question and get the minimum comment's length I say: yes.